# SupportActionMode background color with material design

Tags: android, colors, actionmode

I'm using Toolbar as setSupportActionBar(toolbar). How i can change action mode background color. I try in my App Theme change attribute:

```
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/color</item>
```

But it is not working. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The AppCompat library supports versions of Android that don't have ActionBars, so it needs to define attributes to use that wouldn't exist on those devices. You want to use this:

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/color</item>
```

The same goes for any other style/theme attributes you want to use that have been backported. But you'd use platform ones that exist, like `android:textColor` or `android:background`.

Comment: Do you know a solution to this problem?

Comment: That should work (removing the "android:" prefix), but I can't test it right now.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not so